# Rails - mongoid - create and override using key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I would like to know if there is any simpler (and faster) possibilities to create/override an item in my mongo databse by looking at a Key.

Let me explain :

```
MyObject:

   #<MyObject _id: 5881e885049490276d1d85b9,
    data_table: [...],
    my_key: "test">
```

so this is my object

Today, I need to modify a lot of theses object in a very fast way (very often) updating the data_table

Today I do this :

```
ct = MyObject.where(my_key: "test").first               
ct.update_attributes(data_table: data)
```

But I think I lose a lot of performances, right ?

There is a way I can do like a `create or update` using the key `my_key` to create or override the item ?

Or any other ideas to improves performances ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MyObject.find_or_create_by(my_key: "test").update_attributes(data_table: data)
```

In this case there is no any performance optimizations from mongo side, it will again query db, if not found will create a new record and will update it - just in one line.

Another optimization would be to replace `update_attributes` with `set` if you don't need to run validations on your model.